# passing string to javascript function then show onClick

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I looked over some solutions, but I coudn't figure out how to get this solved
here is my php

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo"<div class='span4'>
      <h2>$row[title]</h2>
      <p>$row[intro]</p>
      <p><a class='btn' onclick=parashow($row['contents'])>View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>";
}
```

I just want to pass the contents into (a function)
and then this function display on click
on div specific id

looking on the web for several hours couldn't help
some say
add
{}
other /'  '/
or
'''$row[contents]'''

stil no help

```
function parashow(x){

//document.getElementById('allrows').style.display = "none";
}
```

I don't know how to pass $row['contents']
to function argument
and then 
get x
and replace it into another div by id ('something')

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo"<div class='span4'>
    <h2>$row[title]</h2>
    <p>$row[intro]</p>
    <p><a class='btn' onclick=parashow('".$row['contents']."')>View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's good to generate **HTML** without PHP:

```
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>

    <div class='span4'>
        <h2><?php echo $row[title]; ?></h2>
        <p><?php echo $row[intro]; ?></p>
        <p><a class='btn' onclick="parashow('<?php echo $row['contents']; ?>')">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: @user2388470 Your welcome. It's also good idea to have a `Template Engine` for your next project. A template engine like [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).

Comment: Thanx again, jut for other guys, I did some search that javascript in some how does not support multiple lines the way I have it up there from database, it will not run but only if you have no break lines. so I found many solution, but I would suggest passing the row ID, or the unique ID for the entry and then from javascript you call a php function that gets the contents based on the unique id of the row. such from table_name where ID="the one you got from javascript passed to the php" I found this the best solution. Other way is to have the contents in a hidden div then just replace it

Comment: However, in my case this messed my style, also you may have so many entry and it will load all contents! even the one you don't wish to see. I hope this help someone there :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) : ?>

    <div class='span4'>
        <h2><?php echo $row[title]; ?></h2>
        <p><?php echo $row[intro]; ?></p>
        <p><a href="#" class='btn' onclick="javascript:parashow('<?php echo $row['contents']; ?>')">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```